# How name-lists are separated in SSH2 algorithm negotiation packet payload?

Tags: ssh

I found in [RFC4253](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-7.1) that:

> 7.1.  Algorithm Negotiation
>
> Key exchange begins by each side sending the following packet:
>
> ```
>   byte         SSH_MSG_KEXINIT
>   byte[16]     cookie (random bytes)
>   name-list    kex_algorithms
>   name-list    server_host_key_algorithms
>   name-list    encryption_algorithms_client_to_server
>   name-list    encryption_algorithms_server_to_client
>   name-list    mac_algorithms_client_to_server
>   name-list    mac_algorithms_server_to_client
>   name-list    compression_algorithms_client_to_server
>   name-list    compression_algorithms_server_to_client
>   name-list    languages_client_to_server
>   name-list    languages_server_to_client
>   boolean      first_kex_packet_follows
>   uint32       0 (reserved for future extension)
> ```
>
> Each of the algorithm name-lists MUST be a comma-separated list of
> algorithm names (see Algorithm Naming in [SSH-ARCH] and additional
> information in [SSH-NUMBERS]).  Each supported (allowed) algorithm
> MUST be listed in order of preference, from most to least.

But I can not find in RFC nothing about how to separate name-lists in payload..

**EDIT:**
All solved with `DataInputStream`, using it's convenient methods `readByte(byte[] b, int off, int len)`, `readInt()` and `readBoolean()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the RFC states, there is more information in `SSH-ARCH` which is [RFC 4251](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4251#page-10).  Here is a partial excerpt of how `name-list` is defined:

> A string containing a comma-separated list of names.  A name-list is
> represented as a uint32 containing its length (number of bytes that
> follow) followed by a comma-separated list of zero or more names.

So after you have read the first 17 bytes of the key exchange packet, you will want to read 4 bytes which will tell you how many bytes (it's ASCII encoded so 1 byte per character) you will need to read to consume the rest of that `name-list`.  Then you repeat this process for each subsequent list.

Comment: Super :) But how to know that this is the last `name-list`?

Comment: Oh, yes, the list is fixed.. Just `..client_to_server` or `..server_to_client` should be picked according to flow direction?

Comment: I found that all fields must be included, but if `name-field` is empty - just `00 00 00 00` value is sent.

Comment: That makes sense.  A `0` length list.